# Create Drop down list as value list dynamically in Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, vba

I've been trying to create a drop down list with the following code:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Me.FNMARemittanceType.RowSourceType = "Value List"

    If Not Me.InvestorName = "Freddie Mac" Then        
        Form_frmPatronInvestorGroupDetails.FNMARemittanceType.RowSource = "Actual/Actual; Scheduled/Scheduled"
    Else
        Form_frmPatronInvestorGroupDetails.FNMARemittanceType.RowSource = "Gold; First Tuesday"
    End If
End Sub`
```

I don't get any errors but my drop down list isn't populating and I'm not quite sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying is pretty logical but you need to use the combobox's AddItem method.

```vb
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Me.FNMARemittanceType.RowSourceType = "Value List"

    If Not Me.InvestorName = "Freddie Mac" Then        
        Form_frmPatronInvestorGroupDetails.FNMARemittanceType.AddItem("Actual/Actual")
        Form_frmPatronInvestorGroupDetails.FNMARemittanceType.AddItem("Scheduled/Scheduled")
    Else
        Form_frmPatronInvestorGroupDetails.FNMARemittanceType.AddItem("Gold")
        Form_frmPatronInvestorGroupDetails.FNMARemittanceType.AddItem("First Tuesday")
    End If
End Sub
```